# linux filesytem options for vmware esxi nfs datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi, filesystems, xfs

I want to use linux based NFS datatstore in vmware esxi 6.5  .Which linux file system is best suited for this prurpose ? I tried xfs,but it has defrangementation issue mentioned here https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/04/xfs-possible-memory-allocation-deadlock-kmem_alloc/.

Comment: So does every other filesystem, given similar usage.

Comment: ESXi doesn't care.

Comment: Hi, your question is bit vague. Choice of filesystem depends on variety of factors such as applications, I/O patters, data volume. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL , I am looking for stable filesystem, something like netapp filesysyem. IO and data volume is not concern.

Comment: After reading, https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/sun-unified-storage/documentation/deploy-10k-vm-zfssa-2245248.pdf  and https://www.assyoma.it/single-post/2015/02/02/ZFS-BTRFS-XFS-EXT4-and-LVM-with-KVM-%E2%80%93-a-storage-performance-comparison  , I think ZFS would be right chioce .